# I looking for sorting by the nearest points to my current location - an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I looking for sorting by the nearest points to my current location - an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D in Swift

Here is my code

```
    let json =  try JSON(data: getJSON(urlToRequest: API_URL_POSITIONS) as Data)
  
            let results: [JSON] = json.array ?? []
         
            let array: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = results
                .map({ $0["vehicle"]["position"] })
                .compactMap({ (json) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D? in
                    guard let longitude = json["longitude"].double else { return nil }
                    guard let latitude = json["latitude"].double else { return nil }
                    return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                })
        
        let   camera  = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!  , longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 10)

        if (mapView == nil)  {
          mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
          self.view.addSubview(mapView!)
        }
         
          mapView?.settings.myLocationButton = true
          mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView?.mapType =  .terrain
        var counter = 0
        let pin = UIImage(named: "bus")!
                                  

        
       for location in array{
           print("location: \(location)")
           let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.icon = pin
           marker.position = location
           marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true
        marker.snippet = results[counter]["vehicle"]["vehicle"]["label"].stringValue
           marker.map = mapView
       counter = counter + 1
        
       }
        
    }
    catch {
        print ("error")
    }
```

I need only return the nearest 5 locations in this code.

Comment: `locations.sort { ... }.prefix(5)`

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to sort the coordinates nearest to the current coordinates.

```
func getNearestPoints(array: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> [CLLocationCoordinate2D]{
    let current = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.longitude)
    var dictArray = [[String: Any]]()
    for i in 0..<array.count{
        let loc = CLLocation(latitude: array[i].latitude, longitude: array[i].longitude)
        let distanceInMeters = current.distance(from: loc)
        let a:[String: Any] = ["distance": distanceInMeters, "coordinate": array[i]]
        dictArray.append(a)
    }
    
    dictArray = dictArray.sorted(by: {($0["distance"] as! CLLocationDistance) < ($1["distance"] as! CLLocationDistance)})
    var sortedArray = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
    for i in dictArray{
        sortedArray.append(i["coordinate"] as! CLLocationCoordinate2D)
    }
    return sortedArray
}
```